# How to invoke a dll

Tags: java, windows, dll, exe

I know there are threads with same title already but the problem i am facing is different from them. I have an java application which is to view/print PDF files. Then i had to get an .exe for the jar which i did using a tool "jartoexe". So i had a command line tool where we can pass arguements and filename. But recently we have a change in requirement where i have to get a dll for the .exe thus generated. I am able to generate the dll using another tool called "Excelsior JET". Now i want to test the dll , whether it is working fine or not. I want to pass the filename and options to view PDF but i have no clue how it will be possible. Can anybody help me with it please??

Comment: Did you read http://www.excelsior-usa.com/kb/000001.html ?

Comment: @manuell That article only applies to Excelsior JET 3.7 and below.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some example programs under samples\Invocation in your Excelsior JET installation directory.